# d3.js-After translate <g> how to add <circle>

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm try to add new `<circle>` after `<g>` was translate.
The `circle` coordinate i'm trying to use mouse event `mousedown` function to get 
coordinate before i translate  i can correctly to add `<circle>` in the mousedown coordinate but after translated `<g>` i can't correctly to add `<circle>`
in the mousedown coordinate.

So i guess after `<g>` was translated i need to redefine new coordinate.But i just no idea how to do that!


Here is my code(i'm use mouse right button to add circles):
[JSbin](https://jsbin.com/qevapiqake/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to to find the mouse position relative to the translate of the group.

```
  var point = document.getElementById('root').createSVGPoint();
  point.x = event.pageX;//mouse position X
  point.y = event.pageY;//mouse position Y
  var newPoint = point.matrixTransform(container.node().getCTM().inverse());
  //newPoint is the place where you will need to draw the circle
      container.append('g')
              .append('circle')
              .attr('cx', newPoint.x)
              .attr('cy', newPoint.y)
              .attr('r', '20');
```

Working code [here](https://jsbin.com/fuyuloguxo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try getBBox method of the group element. It will return the object that has x, y positions. They will tell you by how much element was moved and in what direction.